# How to connect an Android app to an API and display data in a list?

Tags: java, android, json, api

I am trying to make an app that connects to an API (via URL) to retrieve sessions of past workshops.  The API returns all data in JSON format.  I've tried to do a couple of tutorials (using twitter API's) but they are not working.  Here is a link to the tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: @RaghavSood Well, the emulator keeps shutting down.  I get errors like these: 09-20 11:30:17.256: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)  AND  09-20 11:30:17.256: E/AndroidRuntime(678): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.vogella.android.twitter.json/de.vogella.android.twitter.json.ParseJSON}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Marakana tutorials. It's a set of complete video tutorials on Youtube. JSON parsing has been explained with a Twitter timeline example. I have forgotten the video number of that specific tutorial, but with a little fiddling you will surely find it.

Link to first tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RHtKIo_KDI

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommence to use Retrofit.
Less code and get better performance.
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

You can find many code examples and support.

You can just define your API in Interface

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("users/{user}/repos")
  Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

And set the main URL of your API

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
    .build();

GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
```

Final step, Retrofit will convert the response Json to correct Collection

```
Call<List<Repo>> repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
```